How can I make an internal server access the public web behind a jump host
Say that I have a server A:1.2.3.4:1234, which is an totally internal server cannot reach out any public services, such as apt, pip. And I cannot log in A directly. I have to use a jump host B:1.1.1.1:1111. Is there any methods I can use to make A access the public web that I can download some packages.
One methods I know is the ssh proxy. But I only made it without jump host. The procedure is listed below:

Log in the server with Remote forwarding.

ssh -R PortA:localhost:22 XXX@ServerIP


Launch out a Dynamic forwarding in Server.

ssh -ND 1080 -p PortA YYY@localhost


Export the port as proxy in Server.

export all_proxy=socks5://127.0.0.1:1080

Do you have any improvements for this method or other alternatives that I can access apt from the server A.

You probably should check/clear this with your sysadmin, the box is probably airgapped for a reason.
